# Iterating through Web-Pictures (Selenium, Windows Forms, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to loop through a list of Images. Once I replace the backend of the XPath from td/a[1] to td/a[2] I  get the second image in my folder. I would like to get all downloaded files (20 images) in the directory, but I don't know how to iterate through the XPath. Can anyone help me please?

```
var TwentyImages = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//* 
    [@id='ctl00_Main_pnlSearchControl']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/a[2]"));

for (int i = 0; i < TwentyImages.Count; i++)
{                   
  TwentyImages[i].Click();

  var Images = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

  foreach (var xs in Images)
  {
     var ImageUrl = xs.GetAttribute("src");
     WebClient DL = new WebClient();
     DL.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, @"C:\User\Desktop\GoogleImages\.jpg");

  }

  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  driver.Navigate().Back();
  driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and at your "foreach" statement, look at your Images variable. Do you really have all of the images you expect?

Comment: No, i have only one Image in my folder. I mean, the code works depending on the XPath. As soon as the backend of the XPath is changed for example td /a[2] to td/a[3] the third image is displayed in the directory. However, the foreach loop does not run through all images.

Comment: Are you sure your image isn't being overwritten since you aren't specifying a new file name for each iteration of your foreach() loop?

i.e. instead of using a `foreach()`,  use another `for()` statement and instead of using ".jpg", use "...\{index}.jpg" for your file path.

Answer (score 1):

**(Edit Based On New Info In Comments)**

If the XPath to each individual image of your twenty images xpath is e.g. Image1 is located at `(...)/td/a[1]`, and Image2 is located at `(...)/td/a[2]`, etc. then you can simply drop the path to the `a` from your XPath and just use:

```
var TwentyImages = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//* 
    [@id='ctl00_Main_pnlSearchControl']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td"));
```

From there your code will still be able to locate the `img` tags, `src` attributes with each image url you need to download.

Also, don't forget to change the name of our `DL.DownLoad` file for each image per original response below.

**(Original Response)**

Your ".jpg" file name is being overwritten each time `DL.DownloadFile(...)` is called by whatever the image inside of `ImageUrl` is.

You can replace your `foreach()` with another `for()` loop and set the file name to the index value which will give each file a unique name when it saves and prevent it from being overwritten :

Example:

```
for(int xs = 0; xs < Images.Count(); xs++)
{
    var ImageUrl = Images[xs].GetAttribute("src");
    WebClient DL = new WebClient();
    DL.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, $@"C:\Users\Desktop\{xs}.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Yes, you are right. I’ve overlooked that. I had additionally forgotten to upload the HTML code. Take a look to my second question, Stemado. Maybe I can explain the situation like this: “Iterate through multiple Images using the Selenium WebDriver (C#, Windows Forms)”.

Comment: It cost me a great lot of time, but ultimately this works for me wonderfully well!! Thank you very much Stemado. Now,I have all Images in my directory. 
Normally you have to click on each Web-Image to enlarge them. I have therefore implemented the following code snippet in the code: TwentyImages[i].Click(). After each click you will get the enlarged image and then add it to the directory. This was also why the code didn’t worked out. For now though, I’m interested how to solve with the Click(). When I want to enlarge the Web-Image, how do i rewrite the associated code?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using TwentyImages[i].Click() so that you can download the enlarged image whereas right now the above only downloads the thumbnail or smaller images, correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely. With my first code I could only pass one image in the folder. I got an enlarged image in my folder because I added the following addition into the for loop: TwentyImages[i].Click(). Thanks to your support, I get all Images in the directory, but they are just to small.

Comment: Maybe that’s a good idea to solve this with a While-loop. TwentyImages(i).Click and run the for-loop to pass the enlarged image to the folder. Navigate back with the command driver.Navigate().Back() and run the for-loop again. This process should be repeated until all enlarged images are in the directory.